# How can I add shadow to the text in a Blackberry LabelField?

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have tried it overriding `paint()` method inside my own class which extends `LabelField`, but I ignore if there is another simpler way.

My code:

```
protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    int previousColor = graphics.getColor();
    graphics.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
    graphics.drawText(getText(), 2, -2);
    graphics.setColor(previousColor);
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```

What I want to achieve is this:

[image]

EDIT: The [answer by Abhisek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878396/1047055) produces the following result, in case anyone is interested:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If [Abhishek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13878396/813951) does not work, you can try to do it directly in the `paint` method. It's easy, just paint it once in the bg color, then paint it again over it (a few pixels down and left the previous text) in the fg color. Something like this:

```
    protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
        graphics.drawText(getText(), 2, 0);
        graphics.setColor(0x000000);
        graphics.drawText(getText(), 0, 2);
    }
```

Notice how you need 2 extra pixels of height and width, so probably you'll have to override `getPreferredWidth`, `getPreferredHeight` and/or `layout`.

Answer (score 0):

A stab in the dark, but try deriving a font using `Font.derive(style, height, units, aAntialiasMode, aEffects)`, pass `Font.DROP_SHADOW_RIGHT_EFFECT` in the `aEffects` parameter and apply it to the field in question.

Do tell us if it works; I haven't used it since it's undocumented!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Using `Font.DROP_SHADOW_RIGHT_EFFECT` produces in fact a text shadow, but in the same color as the text and in bottom-right direction only.